# My html form submits emppty

Tags: php, html

I have the following html form

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" style="margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 2%;">
                <h1 style="text-align: center">Maak uw FutureGadgetLab account</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="account_created.php">
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Username" placeholder="Username" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="EMail" placeholder="E-Mail" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="date" id="Geboortedatum" placeholder="Geboortedatum" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
            Geslacht: <input type="radio" id="Geslacht" title="Geslacht" value="Man" style="margin-left: 5%;">Man
                    <input type="radio" id="Geslacht" title="Geslacht" value="Vrouw" style="margin-left: 5%;">Vrouw
                    <input type="radio" id="Geslacht" title="Geslacht" value="Anders" style="margin-left: 5%;">Anders
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Straatnaam" placeholder="Straat" style="width: 30%;">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Huisnummer" placeholder="Huis nr." style="width: 9.25%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Postcode" placeholder="Postcode" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Stad" placeholder="Stad" style="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Telefoonnummer" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Maak account" name="Maak_account" id="Maak_account" class="basicButton">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I press the button to submit I get an empty $_POST array, I have tried using $_REQUEST as well but that array is also empty. How do I get the values in my $_POST. I need these values so that I can submit the query to insert a new user in my database.

Could the styling for some reason be messing with the post?
Did I do something wrong with the submit button?
I have no idea what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put name attribute on all input tags which you want send, e.g:

```
<input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Username" placeholder="Username" style="" name="username">
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```
<input class="CreateAccountInput" type="text" id="Postcode" placeholder="Postcode" style="">
```

you have not specify the `name` of any `input`. Specify the `name` for all and try again.

`$_POST` return the array of `name` for all the element present in the form tag, so if name are not assigned, you will get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> You are missing the `name` attribute in every input .

Answer (score 0):

use the attribute " name='name_of_field' " in all the input fields and use them as

$_POST['name_of_field'];